# Magento2 : How to change the footer background color in luma-theme?

Tags: magento2, footer, less-css, luma-theme

I am working on magento-2 version with Luma theme.

I would like to change the footer background color from #f4f4f4 to my desired color.

I found the path is

```
app\design\frontend\Magento\luma\Magento_Theme\web\css\source\_module.less 
line 616
```

I found the property here that 
.page-footer default background is #f4f4f4.

at line 616:

```
.page-footer { i added the new background color }
```

But this did not work. am I in the right area?

How do I change the color?

Comment: Did you recompile the less after you made the change?

Comment: yes several times - cleared all the cache delete all the static folders and also  ran this this bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 3):

I made changes in _variables.less file i.e (/app/design/frontend/web/css/source/_variables.less)

```
@footer__background-color: #ff0000; (RED)
```

Please try below command:

```
php bin/magento clear:cache
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

I hope your changes will be reflect.

Answer (score 0):

Install grunt
delete view_preprocessed under var directory
after that run

- `grunt clean:<theme_name>`
- `grunt less:<them_name>`

Answer (score 0):

Try it by giving `background: #f4f4f4 !important`

Answer (score 0):

I changed it by adding the following to _theme.less in my theme.

/app/design/frontend/*/*/web/css/source/_theme.less
add the following (change #ffffff to your desired color)

@footer__background-color: #ffffff;

After you move that file to your server, you need to flush your static files cache (easiest way is in admin: System > Cache Management and scroll down to "Flush Static Files Cache")

Worked for me.. hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css at your css file:

```
.page-footer 
{ 
  background: #f4f4f4 !important;
}
```

After this please clear the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below command:

```
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```